# Push_swap: sorting 50000 numbers with two rotatable stacks and a limited set of operations

Tags: c, list, algorithm, sorting, push-swap

I have this [push_swap project for school 42](https://github.com/byaliego/push_swap/blob/main/en.subject-pushswap.pdf):

> You have at your disposal a set of int values, 2 stacks and a set of instructions to manipulate both stacks.
>
> Write [a program] in C:
>
> [...] called `push_swap` which calculates and displays on the standard output the smallest program using `Push_swap` instruction language that sorts integer arguments received: [...]
>
> - `sa`: swap `a` - swap the first 2 elements at the top of stack `a`. Do nothing if there is only one or no elements).
> - `sb`: swap `b` - swap the first 2 elements at the top of stack `b`. Do nothing if there is only one or no elements).
> - `ss`: `sa` and `sb` at the same time.
> - `pa`: push `a` - take the first element at the top of `b` and put it at the top of `a`. Do nothing if `b` is empty.
> - `pb`: push `b` - take the first element at the top of `a` and put it at the top of `b`. Do nothing if `a` is empty.
> - `ra`: rotate `a` - shift up all elements of stack `a` by 1. The first element becomes the last one.
> - `rb`: rotate `b` - shift up all elements of stack `b` by 1. The first element becomes the last one.
> - `rr`: `ra` and `rb` at the same time.
> - `rra`: reverse rotate `a` - shift down all elements of stack `a` by 1. The last element becomes the first one.
> - `rrb`: reverse rotate `b` - shift down all elements of stack `b` by 1. The last element becomes the first one.
> - `rrr`:  `rra` and `rrb` at the same time.

#### What I have done

I already have loaded the input of 50 000 numbers in a linked list and a second empty list.

I have to implement a sorting algorithm in C and the goal is to output the smallest amount of instructions that will accomplish that.

I tried with a very simple algorithm that rotated list one until the maximum was on top and then pushed it in list 2 repeatedly until everything was in list 2 and then pushed everything back in list 1, but I was not able to sort lists of more than 5k numbers in a reasonable amount of time.

#### Question

How can I do this efficiently so it works for larger inputs (like 50 000) in a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: You can do a pretty efficient merge sort with these operations.

Comment: So I should put half of list 1 in list 2 , then sort both list at the same time and merge them?

Comment: I think some sort of quick-sort or merge-sort would be the way to go. Storing the nodes that aren't in use is going to be a bit tricky though.

Comment: The problem statement doesn't include what compare operations are allowed. I assume that pa is equivalent to peek_front(list 1), pop_front(list 1), push_front(list 2)?

Comment: Are you allowed some constant-size O(1) extra storage, i.e. local variables to count how many elements are sorted?  If so, you could InsertionSort chunks of 32 elements, and stick them onto the back of a list.  Then MergeSort those chunks, until you've merged everything into one list.

Comment: @PeterCordes Could linked list insertion sort be competitive with quick or merge sort, in this case? I'm not an expert on linked list optimization.

Comment: @BobbySacamano: Not for the whole problem.  For sorting arrays, InsertionSort is used to solve the smallest sub-problems, rather than divide-and-conquering right down to a MergeSort or QuickSort of two or three elements.  InsertionSort is O(n^2), but with very low overhead, so it wins for small problem sizes.  This is what I was suggesting since it's probably true for lists, too, even when you can't use pointer tmp variables to quickly find the insert position.  (you have to modify nodes while rotating to find the insert position, eww.)

Comment: @PeterCordes So it basically operates like heap sort does in introsort? I'm assuming you'd never want to use heap sort on linked lists.

Comment: Yes, in a recursive implementation of qsort or mergesort, you'd do `if (n <= 32) return InsertionSort(..., n);`  And no, you wouldn't want to make a Heap with a list.  Heaps require fast access to element `i*2`.

Comment: what does this have to do with the 'c' language?

Comment: Does the sort need to be conservative?

Comment: With no way to access/compare values you're screwed.

Comment: @greybeard, the asker has not reacted to comments, but I'm confident their code challenge comes from "School 42", so I have edited the question with a link and a quote. This means that the coder will receive the values as arguments, and thus has full knowledge of all values. The challenge is to generate an output that in turn can serve to sort values with these mechanics. But in generating that output, the coder is free to read all values and manipulate them as they wish. It is the output that is restricted to certain instructions only.

Answer (score 6):

I think I've figured out how to do this using quick sort. Here's some pseudocode.

edit: updated pseudocode to focus on what it's doing and not unnecessary syntax

```
quicksort(int n)
    if n == 1 return
    int top_half_len = 0
    choose a median //it's up to you to determine the best way to do this
    for 0 to n {    //filter all values above the median into list 2
        if (value > median) {
            push list 1 top to list 2 //list 2 stores the larger half
            top_half_len++
        }
        rotate list 1 forward
    }

    //reverse the list back to original position
    rotate list 1 backward (n - top_half_len) times

    //push larger half onto smaller half
    push list 2 top to list 1 top_half_len times

    //recursively call this on the larger half
    quicksort(top_half_len)

    //rotate smaller half to front
    rotate list 1 forward top_half_len times

    //recursively call this on smaller half
    quicksort(n - top_half_len) 

    //reverse list back to original position
    rotate list 1 backward top_half_len times
```

Basically, it splits the list into a portion smaller or equal than the median (smaller half) and a portion greater than the median (larger half). Then it calls itself on both of these halves. Once they're length 1, the algorithm is done, since a 1 length list is sorted. Google quick sort for an actual explanation.

I'm think this should work, but I may have missed some edge case. Don't blindly follow this. Also, if you were dealing with arrays, I'd recommend you stop the quick sort at a certain recursion depth and use heap sort (or something to prevent the worst case O(n^2) complexity), but I'm not sure what would be efficient here. **update:** according to Peter Cordes, you should use insertion sort when you get below a certain array size (IMO you should at a certain recursion depth too).

Apparently merge sort is faster on linked lists. It probably wouldn't be too hard to modify this to implement merge sort. Merge sort is pretty similar to quick sort.
[why is merge sort preferred over quick sort for sorting linked lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222730/why-is-merge-sort-preferred-over-quick-sort-for-sorting-linked-lists)

Comment: Thanks a lot its very helpful, I am definitely gonna try this

Answer (score 1):

The problem statement is missing a compare function, so I would define compare(lista, listb) to compare the first node of lista with the first node of listb and return -1 for <, 0 for =, 1 for greater, or all that is really needed for merge sort is 0 for <= and 1 for >.

Also missing is a return value to indicate a list is empty when doing pa or pb. I would define pa or pb to return 1 if source list is not empty and 0 if source list is empty (no node to copy).

It's not clear if the goal is smallest amount of instructions refers to the number of instructions in the source code or the number of instructions executed during the sort.

```
-
```

Smallest number of instructions in the code would rotate list2 based on compares with list1 to insert nodes into list2 at the proper location. Start with a pb, and set list2 size to 1. Then rb or rrb are done to rotate list2 to where the next pb should be done. The code would keep track of list2 "offset" to smallest node in order to avoid endless loop in rotating list2. Complexity is O(n^2).

```
-
```

I'm thinking the fastest sort and perhaps fewest number of instructions executed is a bottom up merge sort.

Do a bottom up merge sort while rotating the lists, using them like circular buffers / lists. Copy list1 to list2 to generate a count of nodes, using the sequence | count = 0 | while(pb){rb | count += 1 }.

Using the count, move every other node from list2 to list1 using {pa, rr}, n/2 times. Always keep track of the actual number of nodes on each list in order to know when the logical end of a list is reached. Also keep track of a run counter for each list to know when the logical end of a run is reached. At this point you have two lists where the even nodes are on list1 and odd nodes are on list2.

Run size starts off at 1 and doubles on each pass. For the first pass with run size of 1, merge even nodes with odd nodes, creating sorted runs of size 2, alternating appending the sorted pairs of nodes to list1 and list2. For example, if appending to list1, and list1 node <= list2 node, use {ra, run1count -= 1}, else use {pa, ra, run2count -= 1}. When the end of a run is reached, the append the rest of the remaining run to the end of a list. On the next pass, merge sorted runs of 2 nodes from the lists, alternately appending sorted runs of 4 nodes to each list. Continue this for runs of 8, 16, ... until all nodes end up on one list.

So that's one pass to count the nodes, one pass to split up the even and odd nodes, and ceil(log2(n)) passes to do the merge sort. The overhead for the linked list operations is small (rotate removes and appends a node), so the overall merge should be fairly quick.

The number of instructions on the count pass could be reduced with while(pb){count +=1}, which would copy list1 to list2 reversed. Then spitting up list2 into list1 would also be done using rrr to unreverse them.

Complexity is O(n log(n)).

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a [least-significant digit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Digit_order) radix sort. As it is given that the input values are all distinct, you can map them to numbers from 0 to n-1, and then radix sort is a very suitable candidate. Of course, to perform that mapping you need to sort the input first, but for that you can use any efficient algorithm (like provided by [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort)).

The algorithm then goes as follows:

- For each bit (of the maximum bit length), starting with the least significant bit do:

  - "filter" stack A so that all values that have the chosen bit set stay on stack A (using `ra`) and the others move to stack B (using `pb`)
  - Move the values from stack B back to stack A (using `pa`). At this point stack A has the values whose bit is set to 1 *below* the ones that have this bit set to 0.

At the end stack A will have the values in their right order.

The number of operations is O(log), which is also the time complexity of the algorithm, provided that the pushswap operations are all implemented with O(1) time complexity (which can be achieved with a circular linked list for each "stack").

The code could look as follows:

```c
Vector *radix_sort(int *values, size_t n) {
    // Create the PushSwap instance with the normalised values
    PushSwap *ps = create_pushswap(array_normalised(values, n), n);
    // Straightforward radix sort, no optimisations
    for (int bit = 1; bit < n; bit *= 2) {
        for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) { // Visit all on A
            if (list_top(ps->a) & bit) { // Top value has the inspected bit set?
                pushswap_do(ps, ra); // Keep it on A
            } else {
                pushswap_do(ps, pb); // Move it to B
            }
        }
        // Move all of B back on top of A
        while (ps->b->length) pushswap_do(ps, pa);
    }
    // The PushSwap instance has collected all operations we did...
    return pushswap_extract_log(ps);
}
```

This function expects the input as an array, and returns an array with push-swap instructions (an array of strings). The `PushSwap` instance is responsible for logging all operations performed on it, and it should return that log with that final `pushswap_extract_log` call.

## All code

#### `array.h`

```c
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void array_print(const int *a, const size_t n);
int *array_shuffle(int *a, const size_t n);
int *array_keys(const size_t n);
int *array_normalised(const int *a, const size_t n);
```

#### `array.c`

```c
#include "array.h"

void array_print(const int *a, const size_t n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%d ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int *array_shuffle(int *a, const size_t n) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        size_t j = i + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (n - i) + 1);
        int t = a[j];
        a[j] = a[i];
        a[i] = t;
    }
    return a; // Returns the same array pointer as given (in-place shuffle)
}

int *array_keys(const size_t n) {
    int *arr = malloc(n * sizeof(arr[0]));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) arr[i] = i;
    return arr;
}

static int compare(const void* a, const void* b) {
   const int *intA = a, *intB = b;
   return (*intA > *intB) - (*intA < *intB);
}

int * array_normalised(const int *a, const size_t n) {
    struct Pair {
        int value;
        int index;
    };
    struct Pair *pairs = malloc(n * sizeof(*pairs));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        pairs[i].value = a[i];
        pairs[i].index = i;           
    }
    qsort(pairs, n, sizeof(*pairs), compare);
    int *res = malloc(n * sizeof(*res));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        res[pairs[i].index] = i;
    }
    return res;
}
```

#### `vector.h`

```c
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define INITIAL_SIZE 50

typedef struct Vector_s Vector;
struct Vector_s {
    size_t max_length;
    size_t length;
    void **data;
};

void vector_push(Vector *arr, void *value);
void *vector_get(Vector *arr, const size_t i);
Vector *create_vector();
void free_vector(Vector *arr);
void vector_print_strings(Vector *arr);
```

#### `vector.c`

```c
#include "vector.h"

void vector_push(Vector *arr, void *value) {
    if (arr->length >= arr->max_length) {  // Need more memory -- double it
        arr->max_length *= 2;
        arr->data = realloc(arr->data, arr->max_length * sizeof(arr->data));
    }
    arr->data[arr->length++] = value;
}

void *vector_get(Vector *arr, const size_t i) {
    return arr->data[i];
}

Vector *create_vector() {
    Vector *arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr));
    arr->max_length = INITIAL_SIZE;
    arr->data = malloc(INITIAL_SIZE * sizeof(arr->data));
    arr->length = 0;
    return arr;
}

void free_vector(Vector *arr) {
    free(arr->data);
    free(arr);
}

void vector_print_strings(Vector *arr) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr->length; i++) {
        printf("%s ", (char*) arr->data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

#### `node.h`

```c
#pragma once

#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node_s Node;
struct Node_s {
    int value;
    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
};

Node *create_node(int value, Node *after);
Node *node_detach(Node *node);
```

#### `node.c`

```
#include "node.h"

Node *create_node(int value, Node *after) {
    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    node->value = value;
    node->next = after ? after->next : node;
    node->prev = after ? after : node;
    node->next->prev = node->prev->next = node;
    return node;
}

Node *node_detach(Node *node) {
    Node *prev = node->prev;
    if (prev != node) {
        node->next->prev = node->prev;
        node->prev->next = node->next;
    }
    free(node);
    return prev != node ? prev : NULL;
}
```

#### `linkedlist.h`

```c
#pragma once

#include "node.h"

typedef struct RotatableLinkedList_s RotatableLinkedList;
struct RotatableLinkedList_s {
    char name;
    Node *top_node;
    size_t length;
};

void list_push(RotatableLinkedList *list, int value);
int list_pop(RotatableLinkedList *list);
int list_top(RotatableLinkedList *list);
void list_rotate(RotatableLinkedList *list);
void list_rev_rotate(RotatableLinkedList *list);
void list_swap(RotatableLinkedList *list);
RotatableLinkedList* create_list(int *values, size_t n);
void list_print(RotatableLinkedList *list);
int list_is_sorted(RotatableLinkedList *list);
void free_list(RotatableLinkedList *list);
```

#### `linkedlist.c`

```c
#include "linkedlist.h"

void list_push(RotatableLinkedList *list, int value) {
    list->top_node = create_node(value, list->top_node);
    list->length++;
}

int list_pop(RotatableLinkedList *list) {
    if (!list->top_node) return -1;
    int value = list->top_node->value;
    list->top_node = node_detach(list->top_node);
    list->length--;
    return value;
}

int list_top(RotatableLinkedList *list) {
    if (!list->length) return -1;
    return list->top_node->value;
}

void list_rotate(RotatableLinkedList *list) {
    if (list->length) list->top_node = list->top_node->prev;
}

void list_rev_rotate(RotatableLinkedList *list) {
    if (list->length) list->top_node = list->top_node->next;
}

void list_swap(RotatableLinkedList *list) {
    if (list->length < 2) return;
    int temp = list->top_node->value;
    list->top_node->value = list->top_node->prev->value;
    list->top_node->prev->value = temp;
}

RotatableLinkedList* create_list(int *values, size_t n) {
    RotatableLinkedList *list = malloc(sizeof(*list));
    list->length = 0;
    list->top_node = NULL;
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        list_push(list, values[i]);
    }
    return list;
}

void list_print(RotatableLinkedList *list) {
   Node *node = list->top_node;
    for (int i = list->length; i > 0; i--) {
        printf("%d ", node->value);
        node = node->prev;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int list_is_sorted(RotatableLinkedList *list) {
    Node *less = list->top_node;
    for (int i = list->length; i > 1; i--) {
        Node *greater = less->prev;
        if (less->value > greater->value) return 0; // Wrong order
        less = greater;
    }
    return 1; // All in the correct order
}

void free_list(RotatableLinkedList *list) {
    while (list->length) {
        list_pop(list);
    }
    free(list);
}
```

#### `pushswap.h`

```c
#pragma once

#include "linkedlist.h"
#include "vector.h"

extern char pa[];
extern char pb[];
extern char sa[];
extern char sb[];
extern char ss[];
extern char ra[];
extern char rb[];
extern char rr[];
extern char rra[];
extern char rrb[];
extern char rrr[];

typedef struct PushSwap_s PushSwap;
struct PushSwap_s {
    RotatableLinkedList *a;
    RotatableLinkedList *b;
    Vector *log;  // Array of instructions ("rb", "ss", "pa", ...)
};

void pushswap_do(PushSwap *ps, char *action);
void pushswap_print(PushSwap *ps);
PushSwap *create_pushswap(int *values, size_t n);
Vector *pushswap_extract_log(PushSwap *ps);
int pushswap_verify(int *values, size_t n, Vector *log);
```

#### `pushswap.c`

```c
#include "pushswap.h"

char pa[] = "pa";
char pb[] = "pb";
char sa[] = "sa";
char sb[] = "sb";
char ss[] = "ss";
char ra[] = "ra";
char rb[] = "rb";
char rr[] = "rr";
char rra[] = "rra";
char rrb[] = "rrb";
char rrr[] = "rrr";

void pushswap_do(PushSwap *ps, char *action) {
    vector_push(ps->log, action);
    if (action == pa)
        list_push(ps->a, list_pop(ps->b));
    else if (action == pb)
        list_push(ps->b, list_pop(ps->a));
    else if (action == sa)
        list_swap(ps->a);
    else if (action == sb)
        list_swap(ps->b);
    else if (action == ss) {
        list_swap(ps->a);
        list_swap(ps->b);
    } else if (action == ra)
        list_rotate(ps->a);
    else if (action == rb)
        list_rotate(ps->b);
    else if (action == rr) {
        list_rotate(ps->a);
        list_rotate(ps->b);
    } else if (action == rra)
        list_rev_rotate(ps->a);
    else if (action == rrb)
        list_rev_rotate(ps->b);
    else if (action == rrr) {
        list_rev_rotate(ps->a);
        list_rev_rotate(ps->b);
    }
}

void pushswap_print(PushSwap *ps) {
    printf("a (top to bottom): ");
    list_print(ps->a);
    printf("b (top to bottom): ");
    list_print(ps->b);
    printf("actions: ");
    vector_print_strings(ps->log);
}

PushSwap *create_pushswap(int *values, size_t n) {
    PushSwap *ps = (PushSwap *)malloc(sizeof(*ps));
    ps->a = create_list(values, n);
    ps->b = create_list(NULL, 0);
    ps->log = create_vector();
    return ps;
}

Vector *pushswap_extract_log(PushSwap *ps) {
    free_list(ps->a);
    free_list(ps->b);
    Vector *log = ps->log;
    free(ps);
    return log;
}

int pushswap_verify(int *values, size_t n, Vector *log) {
    PushSwap *ps = create_pushswap(values, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < log->length; i++) {
        char *action = (char *)vector_get(log, i);
        pushswap_do(ps, action);
    }
    int ok = !ps->b->length && list_is_sorted(ps->a);
    free(ps);
    return ok;
}
```

#### `main.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "array.h"
#include "vector.h"
#include "pushswap.h"

Vector *radix_sort(int *values, size_t n) {
    // Create the PushSwap instance with the normalised values
    PushSwap *ps = create_pushswap(array_normalised(values, n), n);
    // Straightforward radix sort, no optimisations
    for (int bit = 1; bit < n; bit *= 2) {
        for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) { // Visit all on A
            if (list_top(ps->a) & bit) { // Top value has the inspected bit set?
                pushswap_do(ps, ra); // Keep it on A
            } else {
                pushswap_do(ps, pb); // Move it to B
            }
        }
        // Move all of B back on top of A
        while (ps->b->length) pushswap_do(ps, pa);
    }
    // The PushSwap instance has collected all operations we did...
    return pushswap_extract_log(ps);
}

int main(void) {
    // Example runs with doubling input sizes
    for (size_t size = 25; size <= 208000; size *= 2) {
        int *values = array_shuffle(array_keys(size), size);
        Vector *log = radix_sort(values, size);
        printf("Input size: %zu, Actions: %zu, ok: %d\n", 
                size, log->length, verify(values, size, log));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

## Results

The output of the above code is:

```
Input size: 25, Actions: 196, ok: 1
Input size: 50, Actions: 467, ok: 1
Input size: 100, Actions: 1084, ok: 1
Input size: 200, Actions: 2468, ok: 1
Input size: 400, Actions: 5536, ok: 1
Input size: 800, Actions: 12272, ok: 1
Input size: 1600, Actions: 26944, ok: 1
Input size: 3200, Actions: 58688, ok: 1
Input size: 6400, Actions: 126976, ok: 1
Input size: 12800, Actions: 273152, ok: 1
Input size: 25600, Actions: 584704, ok: 1
Input size: 51200, Actions: 1246208, ok: 1
Input size: 102400, Actions: 2646016, ok: 1
Input size: 204800, Actions: 5599232, ok: 1
```

As expected, the number of pushswap actions follows a O(log) trend. A rough prediction of the number of operations is given by this formula:

1.52⋅log<sub>2</sub>(1.35)

You can run it on [repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/PushSwap42RadixSort)

For an algorithm that is optimised for 500 input values, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77295787/5459839), which does the job in an average of 3610 operations for 500 values. It uses the same principle, but uses buckets of varying size instead of the fixed radix buckets you get here, and it uses a kind of insertion sort to get the values from the buckets in their final position.